# Reflection - Collect WinForm Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, windows-runtime

**DESCRIPTION**: I want to take all available controls from over 1000 Winforms from many assemblies. I do not want to have a large refactoring effort. (Small tool,the reason is for internal use)

**WHAT ALREADY DONE**: Got all assemblies, and from every assembly took all types which are interesting for me via `type.IsSubclassOf(selectedType)`.

**INFORMATION OF THE MAIN PROJECT**: Many of the classes have default constructors some not, others refer to other base classes. The project structure is not so optimal because is a product which developed over 15 years.

**PROBLEM**: I tried to take all controls via reflection by using `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` but for many of the classes I took unhandled exceptions or other base class exceptions which were not manageable. Another issue I faced during this procedure was casting. I tried also `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type)` but I did not found how or if it is possible to take controls.

**QUESTION**: Is it possible to collect winForm 'Form' controls with a structure like this without great effort? What could be the different ways to achieve this?

[image]
[image]

**CODE EXAMPLE**

````
static List<AssemblyName> _assemblyList=new List<AssemblyName>();
static List<Type> _typeList = new List<Type>();
static List<Control> _controlList = new List<Control>();

private static void getFormTypes()
{
    foreach (AssemblyName assemblyName in _assemblyList)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)))
            {
                _typeList.Add(type);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void getAllControlsFromFormTypes()
{
    foreach (Type type in _typeList)
    {
        object instance = default;
        
        if (HasValidConstructor(type))
        {
            instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);//Here I have unhandled exceptions from base classes during constructor invoking
            GetValidControls((Control)instance);
        }
    }
}


private static void GetValidControls(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control control in container.Controls)
    {
        GetValidControls(control);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
        {
            _controlList.Add(control);
        }
    }
}

public static bool HasValidConstructor(Type t) => t.IsValueType || !t.IsAbstract && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;```
````

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to create an _instance_ of these form-derived types, or just discover them?

Comment: @Martin: I try to discover all controls. That means, first I tried by creating instance but I faced the above issue.

Comment: I also check a solution of getting all those control names through using of localizable property of the designer of visual studio but still needs too much effort and many forms are corrupted for the designer.

Comment: What I don't understand is _why_ you are creating an _instance_ of the controls?  Why not just enumerate them without creating an instance?

Comment: @Martin : How it is posible to enumerate them without creating an instance?

Comment: I think I must be misundertsanding the objective.  Could you show the code you are currently using?

Comment: What do you want to do with all the controls? Are you sure you want to create instances of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you drop a control in the form, the designer creates a member field for the control. If you haven't changed the `GenerateMember` property to change this behavior, or haven't used data form wizards which create labels without member variables, then you can get all controls using those member fields without instantiating the forms.

For each assembly, you can get a list of forms and controls without instantiating this way:

```
IEnumerable<Type> GetFormsAndControlsTypes(Assembly assembly)
{
    var forms = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(Form).IsAssignableFrom(type));

    var controls = forms.SelectMany(
        form => form.GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(field => typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
            .Select(field => field.FieldType));

    return forms.Concat(controls).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

However, in general such task looks like a code analysis rather than a run-time task.

Comment: Thank you for the useful solution. I do not want to instantiate the classes. I just need to collect all control names and Text (if exists). As I already mention the project is old and the classes(Forms) many times created manually which means than in many cases there are issues during initialization.

Comment: You're welcome. For a quick implementation, the solution is good enough, however such analysis should be done on the code, not on the compiled assembly.

Comment: Is it possible to get the 'Text' property of a control like Button,Label...with this kind of functionality?

Comment: No. Text property is being set in `InitializeComponent` which means it will be set at run-time. So you cannot get it without instantiating the form.

Comment: By instantiating the form and getting instances of the controls and reading their `Text` property.

Comment: Accidentally, delete previous comment on which I asked how to read the Text property from a control .@ Reza Aghaei  give the above answer.